# htaccess renaming into friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URLs:

```
http://example.com/de/cat1/?q=product1
http://example.com/en/cat2/?q=product3
...
```

I would like to rename them as follows.
The first one should become: `http://example.com/de/cat1/product1`. The second one should become: `http://example.com/en/cat2/product3`

In other words I just want to remove "?q=".

My .htaccess does not provide the correct result.
It looks currently as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ ?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

If the users enters `http://example.com/de/cat1/product1` it would turn it into: `http://example.com/de/cat1/?q=/de/cat1/product1`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are capturing the entire uri in a single group and using it as destination querystring. Replace your RewriteRule with the following :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /$1?q=$2 [L]
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Is it possible to keep the SEO friendly URL in the address field instead of having it changed to the real one? I would like to keep `http://example.com/de/cat1/product1` in the address field.

Comment: @user9 yes, its possible. you need to redirect the old url  to the new one. You can use a RewriteRule for this.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. How do I modify my htaccess?